# R- How to take count for a range and include it in Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: r, bar-chart

My data set is:

```
 Gender   Age 
1   female 35     
2   male  34     
3   male  35     
4   male  37     
5   female  34 
6   female 35     
7   male  34     
8   male  35     
9   male  37     
10   female  34
```

If I want to get count for a range such as 30-33 male and 30-33 female (And 33-36 so on) and include in a stacked barchart how it should be? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
library("ggplot2")
```

You could first split your data into bins specified by the age groups.

```
data$group <- cut(data$Age, breaks = c(30,33,36,39), labels = c("30-33","33-36","36-39"), right = TRUE)
```

Then plot it:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you :)